# Want to test Ubuntu touch or Ubuntu phone os on a virgin mobile device. Any recommendations?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

long time Linux participate and virgin mobile customer, I couldn't be happier with my virgin mobile service. It's tops, and Ubuntu has been my favorite os since 2012 when it left all other Linux wanting to be as polished in my opinion. I want to bring those two things together and get in on developing Ubuntu for mobile. Best idea I have so far is unlocked sprint Samsung Galaxy s3 but I don't want to spend the money if it's going to have major issues as I'm not the very best programmer, if any of you have a idea for a less expensive, better performance or both device I could try then please let me and others know!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a programmer - It took me many attempts with both Precise and Trusty desktops to get Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 4 - which should be the"easy" one. I had issues with getting the tools, booting the device- getting the device recognised by the desktop - and I had to add PPA's plus get a PPA management tool. Your chosen phone is not on the list https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/devices/ If you are determined like I was - buy an old Nexus. there is not a great deal of apps yet - that will change as time goes on. Hopefully you have read this already? https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/devices/ If you search Ubuntu Touch here you will see the usual issues people have. Good luck